# What is the right FTP permission for PHP files on a normal LAMP webserver?

Tags: php, linux, ftp, lamp, chmod

I need to know what the right FTP permision is for PHP files on a normal LAMP server? I heard about the linux permision rules and how to modify them using chmod but what are the dangers for a normal user like my client?

For instance, if he modified a PHP file with Filezilla to 777 is the world really allowed to write to the file? Thanks for your help and advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer 755 - it would make the file executable + readable for group and world, while writable for owner only

long answer: it depends on the file itself. usually executable code (php, ruby, perl, python) is set to 755 so that it can be executed by the web server. you can use this http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm to calculate permissions, most FTP clients have this (I believe at least CuteFTP on windows does have it).

Answer (score 1):

By FTP permission you actually mean the permissions on the file. These are chamged using a [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command. In your case 777 doesn't mean *anyone* as such, but rather any user on the server.

Here is a link to a [decent forum thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/5396.htm) on this exact topic. Scroll down to the post by Moose, it is quite informative.

Comment: If i do an HTTP request to the apache server i'm an indirect user right? There's all kinds of sneaky tools. I just wanna make sure i prevent the outside world from editing files.

Comment: When you do a HTTP request, the httpd (probably apache2 now) service is the user that is requesting to use the file, so the permissions of *it* are being used. Luckily, httpd doesn't request to do anything but execute a php file - unless it is specifically told to do so by the PHP script that is being executed at the time.